# Macro going through several modules

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, worksheet-function

Again I am asking for your advice...
I have a couple of macroses, which should be activated by Worksheet_Calculate if a certain cell or range changes on another worksheet. Everything works fine, but I have noticed, that some macroses do not stop at their "End Sub", but jump to another macros, which causes the column in table not to be sorted out. Here is what i have:
Worksheet_Calculate

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Static OldVal As Variant

If Range("AL2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AL2").Value
    Call RF

ElseIf Range("AM2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AM2").Value
    Call SEAL

ElseIf Range("AN2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AN2").Value
    Call SUVPCR

ElseIf Range("AO2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AO2").Value
    Call Segment

ElseIf Range("AU2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AU2").Value
    Call RRC

ElseIf Range("AW2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AW2").Value
    Call WG

ElseIf Range("AY2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AY2").Value
    Call dB

ElseIf Range("BA2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("BA2").Value
    Call Noise_em


End If

End Sub
```

A macro for RF seems to be fine, if i run it alone by F8, it executes without going somewhere else:

```
Sub RF()

On Error Resume Next
If Sheets("All_list").Range("AL2").Value = "No" Then
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("All[[#All],[RF]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ElseIf Sheets("All_list").Range("AL2").Value = "Yes" Then
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("All[[#All],[RF]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ElseIf Sheets("All_list").Range("AL2").Value = "All" Then
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Clear
End If

End Sub
```

But this one (Segment) also works fine alone, but not in Worksheet_calculate, where it for some reason jumps to RF afterwords.

```
   Sub Segment()

Dim x() As Variant

With Sheets("All_list")

.Range("AP2:AP10").Clear
.Range("AO2:AO10" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
.Range("AP2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

x = Application.Transpose(Sheets("All_list").Range("AP2:AP10").Value)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("All[Segment]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:=Join(x, ","), DataOption:=xlSortNormal

End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xl`enter code here`TopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


End Sub
```

It basically means that macros like RF (Seal, SUVPCR) function ok together and even Segment, but after segment nothing seems to sort, everything cuts on it. When I substitute it by for exemple RRC, which is similar, that RRC functions, but again nothing after it.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you turned off events within your worksheet.calculate, or turned off recalculation - otherwise segment will cause a recalc that will trigger the routine a second time

Comment: Just did what you proposed, but nothing has changed, i think the problem is within macro Segment, not worksheet_calculate, but i might be wrong

Comment: Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the top of the sub that calls everything, that might help.

Comment: .... Just make sure to set `Application.EnableEvents = True` again at the end of the sub.

Comment: `Call` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone, thanks for support, it has been figured out

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Static OldVal As Variant
Static OldVal2 As Variant
Static OldVal3 As Variant
Static OldVal4 As Variant
Static OldVal5 As Variant
Static OldVal6 As Variant
Static OldVal7 As Variant
Static OldVal8 As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Range("AL2").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("AL2").Value
    Call RF

ElseIf Range("AM2").Value <> OldVal2 Then
    OldVal2 = Range("AM2").Value
    Call SEAL

ElseIf Range("AN2").Value <> OldVal3 Then
    OldVal3 = Range("AN2").Value
    Call SUVPCR


ElseIf Range("AO2").Value <> OldVal4 Then
    OldVal4 = Range("AO2").Value
    Call Segment

ElseIf Range("AU2").Value <> OldVal5 Then
    OldVal5 = Range("AU2").Value
    Call RRC

ElseIf Range("AW2").Value <> OldVal6 Then
    OldVal6 = Range("AW2").Value
    Call WG

ElseIf Range("AY2").Value <> OldVal7 Then
    OldVal7 = Range("AY2").Value
    Call dB

ElseIf Range("BA2").Value <> OldVal8 Then
    OldVal8 = Range("BA2").Value
    Call Noise_em

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I forgot to assign OldVal to each range separately, that trick made my day.
I also included off/on events for safety as you have proposed, although it seem to have no effect at all in this case. Thanks again for the support